# how to see pdf files in firefox without downloading it by IDM

Tags: firefox, pdf, firefox-addon

when any pdf files are opened in firefox browser, it is captured by IDM .it is not opened in browser. please tell how to see pdf files in brwoser without disabling IDM.
when i click on any link of pdf files , it is automatically captured by iDM

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[View PDF files in Firefox without downloading them](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/view-pdf-files-firefox-without-downloading-them)

Comment: Nice thanks for finding this article for him. @user10220 the important part is in options under the applications tab: [image](https://support.cdn.mozilla.net/media/uploads/gallery/images/2013-02-23-15-01-33-b3b88b.png)